# Ensure exactly one space after each colon in CSS in Netbeans

Tags: css, regex, netbeans, sass

I'm editing old SCSS in Netbeans and want to format it to be prettier.

I want to do a regex "find and replace" on all colons that are not followed by a space. I want to ensure that exactly one space follows each colon.

Here is some sample SCSS:

```
display: block;
width:800px;
height:20px;
text-align:center;
```

The regex would ignore the first line and then for the next 3 lines would add a space after each colon.

I know there are special corner cases such as `input.focus::-webkit-input-placeholder`.  I could do each find-and-replace one by one rather than "replace all". I could then skip over the corner cases.

If there is a non-regex way to do this, that would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this search

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]:)([a-zA-Z0-9#])
```

And replace it with

```
$1 $2
```

Comment: This worked great for me in Sublime. I added the semicolon so I wouldn't match pseudo selectors. Find what: `(\S*:)(\S*;)`. Replace with: `$1 $2`.

Comment: Be careful: the semicolon can be omitted in the last property of a declaration...

Comment: This also missing lines such as `color:#368000;`

Answer (score 1):

A regex search I used recently that worked:

`([\t\s,;\{])([a-zA-Z\-]+):([\'a-zA-Z\d,\-%#]+((\s*,\s*|\s+)[\'a-zA-Z\d,\-%#]+)*([\r\n][\t\s]*)*[;|\}])`

Replacement

`$1$2: $3`

I tested it in notepad++ (v6.7.5) and sublime (build 3083). This regex covers multiple scenarios such as the following:

```
.some-class {
    font-family:'Arial Regular', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    width:25%;
    height:10px;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #d7d7d7
}
```

It will ignore psuedo selectors also.

Answer (score 1):

@Ian G's answer is a little closer, but still incomplete. The following rules will not be caught by it:

```
background:url("img/test.jpg");
font-size:.8em;
height:auto !important;
line-height:1.2em;
width:calc(100% - 5px);
```

I've modified it a little further to catch those rules:

```
([\t\s,;\{])([a-zA-Z\-]+):([\'a-zA-Z\d,\-\:\+\/%#\!\.\"\(\)]+((\s*,\s*|\s+)[\'a-zA-Z\d,\-%#\!\.\"\(\)]+)*([\r\n][\t\s]*)*[;|\}])
```

The only scenario I could think of that still doesn't work with that is an inline data URI:

```
background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

The `;` in the MIME type throws that off. However, the modification will catch slightly more errant CSS formatting.